# PowerPivot refresh based on last refresh and date column in table

Tags: sql, powerpivot

Is there a way to have PowerPivot to compare it's last refresh against a date in a table that it grabs?  I'd like to have it simply add additional rows.

An additional complexity is this:
2 tables grabbed for PowerPivot let's say user and usage.  I'd like it to get a new copy of user but add additional rows to usage by comparing last refresh against usage.usage_date

Answer (score 0):

first, there is no straightforward way to get the last refresh date for PowerPivot. Methods do exists, please google.
Second, it is not clear how you are going to add rows in a table based on another. If you are thinking VBA, you can create individual connection for each table and first refresh user table and refresh usage afterward. Individual connection simplify requirement like this, whole PowerPivot can be refreshed with a single line/command.

Thanks